# How to Run WSO2 Streaming Integrator Editor

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I installed WSO2 Streaming Integrator using [Docker Container](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/streaming-integrator/setup/installing-si-using-docker/). There is no word about how to install the editor in this tutorial but I need to have WSO2 SI editor.
please give some points about how to install editor for developing Siddhi application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, a docker image is not available for the SI tooling distribution. You can use the Zip Archive of Streaming Integrator tooling from [here](https://wso2.com/integration/streaming-integrator/#) to create a docker image.